# validating inputs in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

```
 var test2Regex = /^[0-9]*$/;
```

The above allows the input to be only numbers and no blanks

```
var i=0;
var pro = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
pro[i] = document.getElementById('pro' + i);
   if(!pro[i].value.match(test2Regex)){
        //alert("You entered: " + pro[i].value)
        inlineMsg('pro' + i,'Invalid Input',10);
        return false;
    }
}
```

is using the match query the right way to do this as it does work
on single variable not using the getelement id i.e

```
var phoneno = form.phoneno.value;
if(!phoneno.match(test1Regex)) {
    inlineMsg('phoneno','You have entered an invalid Char.',10);
    return false;
}
```

the get element is the only difference but I need that in for it to pass the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex.test method

```
if(!test2Regex.test(pro[i].value)){
    //invalid input, blah-blah-blah
}
```